# Python string parsing name and number

Tags: python

I have to parse a data source:

```
my_string = "Alex - 30% / Bob - 23.33%"
```

Here `my_string` contains two names but it could also be one person in length or three.

I want to obtain a dictionary mapping the names to the values:

```
result = {'Alex': 30, 'Bob': 23.33}
```

I've tried multiple approaches, such as regular expressions and splitting the string, but I just can't seem to crack this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.findall()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = "Alex - 30% / Bob - 23.33%"
>>> r = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]*) - (\S+)%', my_string)
>>> r
[('Alex', '30'), ('Bob', '23.33')]
```

You can then create a dictionary:

```
>>> result = {name:float(val) for name,val in r}
>>> result
{'Alex': 30.0, 'Bob': 23.33}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Split first on the `/` to get a list of your names.
Then split each item of the list by `-` to get your individual fields.

Example:

```
finalDict = {}
values = my_string.split(" / ")
for(item in values):
    entry = item.split(" - ")
    finalDict[entry[0]] = float(entry[1].strip("%")) #if you want second field as a float
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
>>> my_string = "Alex - 30% / Bob - 23.33%"
>>> {i.split(' - ')[0]:float(i.split(' - ')[1].rstrip('%')) for i in my_string.split(' / ') }
{'Bob': 23.33, 'Alex': 30.0}
```

**or**

```
>>> s = my_string.split(' / ')
>>> {i.split(' - ')[0]:float(i.split(' - ')[1].rstrip('%')) for i in s}
{'Bob': 23.33, 'Alex': 30.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{name: float(value[:-1]) for name, value in (person.split(' - ') for person in my_string.split(' / '))}
```

Comment: You don't need to call tuple

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.split repeatedly:

```
my_string = "Alex - 30% / Bob - 23.33%"
result = dict([(s.split()[0],s.split()[2][:-1]) for s in my_string.split('/')])
```

The first parses based on the '/', and the second parses based on the '-'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd find it useful:

```
dict(substring.split(' - ') for substring in string.split(' / '))
```